# Is it possible to create a pipe like sql in

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, pipe

is it possible to create a pipe for filtering an array according to multiple fields? but these fields can change so filter function has to include all included fields.

```
values.filter((value) => value[field] === args[0] || .... || value[field] === args[n])
```

So how does a pipe like this created?
How is filter function situation handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create search pipe for filter as below. it will accept first parameter as your main object which hold all value and second parameter hold value object which you have to filter from main one.

**Define Objects:**

```
data: any[];
searchValue:any[];
constructor(){
  this.data = [ 'apple', 'banana', 'carrot', 'pear', 'peach', 'orange','mango', 'grapes', 'lime', 'lemon' ];
  this.searchValue = [ 'apple',  'peach', 'orange' ]    
}
```

**Search Pipe:**

```
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items:any[], args:string[]):any[] {
        if (typeof items === 'object') {
            var resultArray = [];
            if (args.length === 0) {
                resultArray = items;
            }
            else {
                for (let item of items) {
                    if (item != null && args.indexOf(item)>=0) {
                        resultArray.push(item);
                    }                       
                }
            }
            return resultArray;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="item" *ngFor="let item of data | searchPipe: searchValue">
  {{item}}
</div>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: thanks for your post but my aim is filtering array by using properties of object.

Comment: I think my post can help you, you have to may be do some modification in your logic

Answer (score 0):

@sandip patel thanks for your answer.
I slightly modified your answer.

```
         import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

    @Pipe({
        name: 'inFilter',
        pure: false
    })

    export class InFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
        transform(items: any[], args: any): any[] {
            if (typeof items === 'object') {
                var resultArray = [];
                if (args.args.length === 0) {
                    resultArray = items;
                }
                else {
                    for (let item of items) {
                        if (item != null && args.args.indexOf(item[args.key]) >= 0) {
                            resultArray.push(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return resultArray;
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }

        }
    }
```

so i can filter my array which propery i want.